# In Excel, how to group data by date, and then do operations on the data?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, pivot-table

I have Excel 2003. My data is like this:

```
01/10/2010 0.99
02/10/2010 1.49
02/10/2010 0.99
02/10/2010 0.99
02/10/2010 0.99
03/10/2010 1.49
03/10/2010 1.49
03/10/2010 0.99
```

etc. In fact it is a list of sales every day. I want to have something like this:

```
01/10/2010 0.99
02/10/2010 4.46
03/10/2010 3.97
```

I want to group by date, and sum the column B. I'd like to see the evolution of the sales over time, and display a nice graph about that.

I have managed to create pivot tables that almost do the job: they list the number of 0.99 and 1.49 each day, but I can't find a way to simply sum everything and group by date.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick step-by-step break down of what I've done, which I think achieves what you're after.

First, prepare data and select the relevant columns:

[image: Data in Excel Sheet]

Create the Pivot Table, I've done so in a seperate sheet, it doesn't really matter where.

[image: Empty Pivot Table]

Drag the **Date** field to the "Drop Row Fields Here" box on the left.
Drag the **Value** field to the "Drop Data Items Here" box in the middle.
This will not quite be right, as it counts by default:

[image: Pivot Table of Date with count of value]

Double-click the "Count of Value" header in the top-left and set the "Summarise by" option to "Sum".

[image: Pivot Table of Date with total sum of value]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much for this very detailed answer.